# Create QGIS action that shows point at coordinate on click

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point

In QGIS 2.18 in my current point-layer I have related coordinates, which I would like to pop up when clicking on a point in the point layer. I try to use QGIS "Action" for this.

Simplified example of my point-Layer:

```
ID_____ | X_____ | Y_____ | Xrel__ | Yrel__

----------

A______ | 1.0___ | 1.0___ | 1.2___ | 1.3___  
A______ | 1.0___ | 1.0___ | 1.5___ | 1.0___  
A______ | 1.0___ | 1.0___ | 1.0___ | 1.1___  
B______ | 2.0___ | 2.0___ | 2.2___ | 1.9___
```

---

So when clicking on point A (or nearby coordinate of point A) I would like to highlight the coordinates of Xrel and Yrel corresponding to A. Is there a way to do this using the Generic or Python action type?

Preferably when selecting another point or deselecting, the highlighted coordinates disappear.

I made a sample script that follows the steps I want to do. It is not in pygis style, but more a guideline of what I want to achieve:

```
# here some code to load all necessary python gis modules

# create a small buffer around the point where the user clicked
coordinateBuffer = buffer(clickedPointOnMap,0.0001)

# find all features within that buffer in the feature class (point layer)
pointsInBuffer = intersect(pointLayer,coordinateBuffer)

# statement to make sure to remove previous created points
    if isempty(pointsInBuffer)
        if isnotempty(pointsOnMap)
        remove(pointOnMap)
    else break
    else
    if isnotempty(pointsOnMap)
        remove(pointOnMap)
    else
        # extract coordinates in the attribute table of the point layer
        toHighlight = pointsInBuffer[:, (Xrel,Yrel)]

        # create a point and set layout of the toHighlight points layer
        pointsOnMap = make(toHighlight)
        pointsOnMap(fill_color_rgb(255,211,0))}
```

[image: Action panel in QGIS]